# 'docker-compose' creating multiple instances for the same image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I need to start multiple containers for the same image. If I create my compose file as shown below, it works fine.

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  app01:
    image: app
  app02:
    image: app
  app03:
    image: app
  app04:
    image: app
  app05:
    image: app
```

Is there an easy way for me to mention the number of instances for the compose instead of copy and pasting multiple times?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

#### Updated answer (Jul 2023)

The old "scale" feature is [now called `replicas`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#replicas) and it is part of the current Docker Compose specs, 2.19.1 as of writing.

Note that `replicas` is ignored if you name your container using `container_name: myname`. You must let the Docker generate the names.

```
services:
  myapp:
    image: awesome/webapp
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 6
```

#### Updated answer (Oct 2017)

As others mentioned, the Docker API has changed. I'm updating my answer since it's the one most people will probably look at.

```bash
docker-compose up -d --scale app=5
```

Unfortunately, we cannot specify this in a *docker-compose.yml* file currently as of version 3.5 (1.18.0 in re-numbered version).

Details: 
They did introduce the `scale` option for version 2.2 and 2.3 of docker-compose, but they removed it for version 3.0. Also, to use version 2.2 or 2.3 you would need to download an older version of the *docker-compose* tool. The current version does not support 2.2 or 2.3 (it does support 2.0 or 2.1 however).
There is also a new `deploy` section with `replicas: 5` but it's only for swarm mode.

---

#### Old Answer

```bash
docker-compose scale app=5
```

See *[docker compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/)*.

Then you only need this *docker-compose* file:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: app
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify this in the docker-compose file, so that when you run `docker-compose up`, it will run the preconfigured number of instances?

Comment: How do you set the port range for the containers?

Comment: @MuhammadAbrar You specify the ports the same as with any service. Either use `expose:` for exposing ports to other services on the same network or `ports:` to expose ports to the host (publicly accessible). https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-1

Comment: Notice that omitting `-d` (daemon mode) means *all* containers started using the same `docker-compose` file will stop once Ctrl+C is used to terminate the last scaled container. Very dangerous. I'd suggest adding `-d` to `docker-compose up` in the answer above, to avoid copy/paste disasters.

Comment: @MarcoChiappetta good point. I usually do `up -d`. Typo this time.

Comment: @Bernard How to ensure that each instance has a different port exposed to the host?

Comment: @xkcd You can use "expose: 4000" instead of "expose: 4000:4000". This will give each instance its own IP address on the internal network. The Docker daemon has a DNS resolver which will round robin the requests to port 4000 on the host to one of the instances. In practice though, you would put a proper load balancer in front (nginx, haproxy, ...) and not expose your instance to the outside world.

Comment: Is this answer still valid?

Comment: thanks for the heads up @alper. I'm not following Docker as closely as I used to so my answer was seriously outdated and Docker Compose has a horrible track record for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 77):

You can do it with `replica` as mentioned in *[Compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#replicas)*:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
    image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 6
```

One can use `docker-compose --compatibility up` to make Docker accept a deploy section without using swarm.

Comment: Replicas is only for deploying in a swarm.

Comment: @KenJ does that make a functional difference?

Comment: Yes, if the option is ignored by ordinary `docker-compose up` commands.

Comment: I don't see in the linked docs that this is ignored by docker-compose up? All I see is that creating a replica is the default.

Comment: The `deploy` intro/header docs state that the entire section is ignored by `docker-compose up` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy)

Comment: So using a standalone docker-compose without swarn, I have no chance to start multiple instance without declaring multiple containers in the compose-file?

Comment: One can use `docker-compose --compatibility up` to make docker accept `deploy` section without using swarm.

Comment: @NikolaPetkanski your comment should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @NikolaPetkanski : that is NOT the correct answer. I get "ERROR: for database  Cannot create container for service database: Conflict. The container name "/mysql" is already in use by container "

Comment: @Octavian using `docker-compose --compatibility up`, no providing the container name will work

Comment: The `replica` documentation *may* have moved to [another page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#replicas).

Comment: Can we assign different port numbers for each created replica?

Answer (score 44):

The `scale` command is now deprecated, and you should use `up` instead.

```
docker-compose up --scale app=2
```

More details are on *[docker compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up)*.

Comment: This is actually problematic and it's not covered in the doc. If we have services A, B, C and we do docker-compose up --scale B=2, it's going to start all A, B, C, so it's equivalent to docker-compose up --scale A=1 --scale B=2 --scale C=1. I'm pretty sure this is not what the user wants in many cases.

Comment: @fssilva, This command worked in my case. However I have to modify my compose file.       (1) remove container name from compose file to resolve "name is already in use by container' error.  (2) remove explicit port bindings to resolve "failed: port is already allocated" error.

Comment: @ShivaWu in that case specify the desired service at the end e.g.`docker-compose up --scale appB=2 appB` to only start service B. I normally do `docker-compose up` then if I want additional instances of a particular service I follow up with `docker-compose up --scale appB=5 appB`

Answer (score 13):

You can do this:

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  service1: &service_1
    image: app

  service2:
    <<: *service_1

  service3:
    <<: *service_1
```

For more information on `<<`, see *[What is the << (double left arrow) syntax in YAML called, and where's it specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063361/what-is-the-double-left-arrow-syntax-in-yaml-called-and-wheres-it-specced)*.

Comment: This tricky basically defined multiple services. Only applicable for a worker container, if your container provide service to others, supposed to `expose` port, the other containers will not able to connect via service discovery.

Comment: If you are using multiple docker-compose files (like when calling docker-compose with the -f flag or setting the COMPOSE_FILE env variable), the anchor must be defined in the same file you are referencing it, can't have them splitted in different files.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me well:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    ...
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
```

and run the command then:

```
docker-compose --compatibility up
```