# How to share environment variables in parallel Bitbucket pipeline steps?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

So, I am using Bitbucket pipelines to deploy my application. The app consists of two components: 1 and 2. They are deployed in two parallel steps in the Bitbucket pipeline:

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    1-deploy-to-test:
      - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Deploying 1
            image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
            script:
              - SERVICE_ENV=test
              - GCLOUD_PROJECT="some-project"
              - MEMORY_LIMIT="256Mi"
              - ./deploy.sh
        - step:
            name: Deploying 2
            image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
            script:
              - SERVICE_ENV=test
              - GCLOUD_PROJECT="some-project"
              - MEMORY_LIMIT="256Mi"
              - ./deploy2.sh
```

The environment variables `SERVICE_ENV`, `GCLOUD_PROJECT` and `MEMORY_LIMIT` are always the same for deployments 1 and 2.

Is there any way to define these variables once for both parallel steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [User-defined variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html#Variablesinpipelines-User-definedvariables) in Pipelines. For example, you can configure your `SERVICE_ENV`, `GCLOUD_PROJECT` and `MEMORY_LIMIT` as a Repository variables and they will be available to all steps in your pipeline.

Comment: So there is no way to set it in some higher level in the yaml, so that it is included in the sourcecode?

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, here's a glimpse of how we currently handle this, inspired from all the other solutions found in Bitbucket's forums.

To allow parallel tasks to re-use deployment variables (currently cannot be passed between steps), we use the bash Docker image first to set environment variables in an artifact. The pure bash image is very fast (runs under 8 seconds usually).

Then all other tasks can run in parallel benefiting of the deployment and repository variables that we usually set, all of that bypassing the current Bitbucket Pipelines limitations.

```yaml
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &set_env
        name: Set multi-steps env variables
        image: bash:5.2.12
        artifacts:
          - set_env.sh
        script:
          ## Pass env
          - echo "Passing all env variables to next steps"
          - >-
            echo "
            export USERNAME=$USERNAME;
            export HOST=$HOST;
            export PORT_LIVE=$PORT_LIVE;
            export THEME=$THEME;
            " >> set_env.sh
    - step: &git_ftp
        name: Git-Ftp
        image: davidwebca/docker-php-deployer:8.0.25
        script: 
          # check if env file exists
          - if [ -e set_env.sh ]; then
          -   cat set_env.sh
          -   source set_env.sh
          - fi
          # ...

branches:
    staging:
      - parallel: 
        - step: 
            <<: *set_env
            deployment: staging
      - parallel:
        - step: 
            <<: *git_ftp
        - step: 
            <<: *root_composer
        - step: 
            <<: *theme_assets
```

According to the forums, Bitbucket staff is working on a solution to allow more flexibility on this as we speak (2022-12-01) but we shouldn't expect immediate release of this as it seems complicated to implement safely on their end.

Answer (score 0):

as was explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481242/make-variable-visible-across-steps-in-bitbucket-pipelines), you can define the Environment Variables and copy them to a file.

After that you can share that file between steps as an Artifact.