# Update Task Definition for ECS Fargate

Tags: json, docker, bitbucket, envsubst

I have an ECS Fargate cluster that is being deployed to through BitBucket Pipelines. I have my docker image being stored in ECR. Within BitBucket pipelines I am utilizing pipes in order to push my docker image to ECR and a second pipe to deploy to Fargate.

I'm facing a blocker when it comes to Fargate deploying the correct image on the deployment. The way I have the pipeline is setup is below. The docker image gets tagged with the BitBucket Build Number for each deployment. Below is the pipe for the Docker image that gets built and pushed to ECR:

```
name: Push Docker Image to ECR
script:
  - ECR_PASSWORD=`aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`
  - AWS_REGISTRY=$ACCT.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  - docker login --username AWS --password $ECR_PASSWORD $AWS_REGISTRY
  - docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE .
  - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image:1.6.2
    variables:
      IMAGE_NAME: $DOCKER_IMAGE
      TAGS: $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

The next part of the pipeline is to deploy the image, that was pushed to ECR, to Fargate. The pipe associated with the push to Fargate is below:

```
name: Deploy to Fargate
script:
  - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecs-deploy:1.6.2
    variables:
      CLUSTER_NAME: $CLUSTER_NAME
      SERVICE_NAME: $SERVICE_NAME
      TASK_DEFINITION: $TASK_DEFINITION
      FORCE_NEW_DEPLOYMENT: 'true'
      DEBUG: 'true'
```

Within this pipe, the attribute for `TASK_DEFINITION` specifies a file in the repo that ECS runs its tasks off. This file which is a JSON file, has a key pair for the image ECS is to use. Below is an example of the key pair:

```
"image": "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$DOCKER_IMAGE:latest",
```

The problem with this line is that the tag of the image is changing with each deployment.

What I would like to do is have this entire deployment process be automated, but am having this step prevent me from doing that. I had came across this [link](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-to-amazon-ecs/) that shows how to change the tag in the task definition in the build environment of the pipeline. The article utilizes `envsubst`. I've seen how `envsubst` works, but not sure how to use it for a JSON file.

Any recs on how I can change the tag in the task definition from latest to the Bitbucket Build Number using `envsubst` would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using a JSON and YAML capable programming language? Like python or perl?

Comment: Why update the task definition. A new task def be created with each deployment and image tag can refer to commit ID to be unique. Now to pass the image tag/path between steps, see this link (env file be shared as artifact): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481242/make-variable-visible-across-steps-in-bitbucket-pipelines