# Is it possible to define constants in .yml files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I am writing a docker-compose.yml and have several containers that require certain environment variables set to the same value (ie CONTACT_EMAIL).

Currently my docker-compose.yml looks something like this:

```
version: '2.0'
    services:
        service1:
            ...
            environment:
                CONTACT_EMAIL: webmaster@example.com
            ...
        service2:
            ...
            environment:
                CONTACT_EMAIL: webmaster@example.com
            ...
        service3:
            ...
            environment:
                CONTACT_EMAIL: webmaster@example.com
            ...
```

Is there a way to define a variable/ constant WEBMASTER *within the yaml file* and assign the value to the CONTACT_EMAIL environment variables?

Or is it possible to define an environment for all services *(within the yaml file)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
version: "2.0"

x-common-env: &common_env
  CONTACT_EMAIL: webmaster@example.com

services:
  service1:
    ...
    environment:
      <<: *common_env

  service2:
    ...
    environment:
      <<: *common_env
      ANOTHER_ENV: abc
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on how that works?

Comment: As you can see above:  
- First, you create a reusable definition named `common_env` or whatever you like, containing all the settings that you could reuse later.  
- When using it, use syntax `<<: *common_env` to print everything you have inside that definition.
Test the syntax using: `docker-compose config`

Comment: Interesting. And the x-common-env label serves no practical purpose?

Comment: yeah, just make sure it is unique, and start with `x-`. It is called "extension" if you curious.

Comment: @Benj Some more details on YAML anchors: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41063361/1108305, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6651275/1108305.

Answer (score 1):

You can use env file, create env file where you add all your values and refer the same file in all services in docker-compose.
Check this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: This is actually what I ended up using