# Error Map Keys Must be unique while using YAML extension field in docker compose for django application

Tags: django, docker, yaml

hi I have this in my **YAML** file , and I am getting error `Map keys must be unique` at `<<: *common` in django service.

```
version: '3.4'

x-common: &common
  restart: unless-stopped
  networks: docker_django

x-django-build: &django-build
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./DockerFile.dev

services:

  django:
    <<: *django-build
    <<: *common
    container_name: docker_django_dc01
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`<<: *reference` isn't actually a keyword; it's an ordinary YAML mapping entry with the key `<<` that happens to have special treatment.  On SO, see [What is the << (double left arrow) syntax in YAML called, and where's it specced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063361/what-is-the-double-left-arrow-syntax-in-yaml-called-and-wheres-it-specced); that in turn refers to the [Merge Key Language-Independent Type for YAML™ Version 1.1](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) draft specification.

Since `<<` is a mapping key, YAML parsers that try to convert mappings into dictionaries won't like to see multiple of it.  Conversely, the spec allows a sequence as the value, so for this specific use you could write

```yaml
<<: [*django-build, *common]
```

(Also consider whether you need this many custom settings.  Compose [provides](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) a network named `default` for you so you don't typically need `networks:`; if you just name your Dockerfile, well, `Dockerfile` then you can use a one-liner `build: .`    That would avoid needing the YAML alias/anchor syntax here.)