# How can I run multiple Docker containers?

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to run as many Docker containers, as many I have CPU cores. So, I used command:
`docker run --cpus="16" --link=mongo_dev:mongodb -d -p 8001:8000 --name app myapp`

Also, I tried:

`docker run --cpuset-cpus="0-15" --link=mongo_dev:mongodb -d -p 8001:8000 --name app myapp`

But it runs only one container. Or did I misunderstand the use of this command?
Is it real to run a multiple Docker containers in one machine? As I know, I can't use node.js [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module to make multiple instances of my app in one Docker container because it runs only in 1 CPU core, does it?

Comment: If I understand this document correctly https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler
You use those commands to select which cpu cores it should use. If you want to run multiple docker containers, you use the run command multiple times, or use a docker-compose. Hope this helps

Comment: @H.Hakvoort can I use Docker Swarm for one machine to make as many workers, as I want?

Comment: I suppose you could.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  You can run multiple containers on one server, and it is not restricted to the number of CPUs.

Your command creates and starts exactly 1 container that has access to at most 16 CPUs (and in the 2nd example only precisely CPUs 0-15).

What you want to do is execute your command N times for N containers.  If you wish to restrict containers to use only one CPU each use --cpus=1.  If you further wish to restrict containers to never share a CPU, use --cpuset-cpus=I, where I is an integer 0-15 for each container.  But in reality, the kernel is pretty good at scheduling, unless you are doing additional tuning, I would let it do it's job.

Answer (score 2):

If you use docker-compose, you can use `scale` parameter to run multiple instances of the same image.

This was already answered here [docker-compose creating multiple instances for the same image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663096/docker-compose-creating-multiple-instances-for-the-same-image)

And check out the official doc for docker-compose https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I implement multi-containers with wercker? Because I don't use a docker-compose.

Comment: Update: 'docker-compose scale' is now obsolete. suggestion is to use 'docker-compose up': https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/