# How to run two instances of a Service without binding to specific port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two problem Statement for running the docker container.

1. Run two instances of a docker container.

I am running a container say **test-service**. When I execute the command **Only one** container named as **test-service** get created. I want to change the command and create one more instance of the container.

2. Dynamic Port number Allocation to the container.

I am binding the port say **8080:8080**. I want to configure it in such a way that the port number will be dynamic.

The command which I am using to run the container is as below:

```
docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network ${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

The test-service is a node service.

Please let me know what modifications are needed in the above command.

Comment: You should use `docker stack` instead of `docker-compose` for this. Would make things a lot more easier for you

Answer (score 0):

For 2nd question:

Use `--publish-all` flag instead of providing port mapping.

```
$ docker run --publish-all --network ${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

This will publish a container's port(s) to the host port. Host port will be dynamic. And all container ports will be exposed.

But if you want to expose specific port, use `-p :<port>`

```
$ docker run -p :${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network ${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

Leave `${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}` part empty, then a port will be selected dynamically.

For 1st question:

You can use docker-compose. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39663096/1924666).

Or, you can run `docker run` multiple time. In this case, use different `--name`