# Spring how to scale instance?

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud

I want to design a microservice system.
I see it this way. I send all requests to the spring-gateway-api.

Then he sends it to the service (let's call it **order**)
But how can I dynamically increase/decrease the number of instances of the order service.
What should I do if the sping-gateway-api service starts dying from the number of requests?

**How are such issues resolved**?

Comment: Scaling instances is typically handled by the platform your apps are running on

Comment: @spencergibb I don't understand. I have 1 instance. Let's say this application is in docker. How do I set its scalability ?

Comment: Docker isn't a platform. Docker swarm, kubernetes, or hashicorp nomad are container management systems that do what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I dynamically increase/decrease the number of instances of the order service.

Scaling(I assume you mean horizontal) can be achieved by running more instances of order your service. In simple terms, it means to run multiple instances of your docker image. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663096/docker-compose-creating-multiple-instances-for-the-same-image) [reference2](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/how-to-use-docker-compose-to-run-multiple-instances-of-a-service-in-development/)

> What should I do if the sping-gateway-api service starts dying from the number of requests?

You can study more about circuit breaker design pattern. This type of issue can be resolved with circuit breaker.